# method invocation 'toString' may produce 'java.lang.NullPointxception'

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

```
package com.tp468.dell.automatedfishpondmonitoringsystem;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.support.annotation.NonNull;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;

import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;

import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;

import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView Temperature;

    DatabaseReference dRef;

    String status;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Temperature = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);

        dRef= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

        dRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                status=dataSnapshot.child("Temperature").getValue().toString();

                Temperature.setText(status);

            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to check dataSnapshot.child("Temperature").getValue() if this expression returns a null or not.. just put up a null check in if condition before using toString on it.

Comment: how to resolve this error??

Comment: @TusharChaudhari by checking if it's null or not

Comment: pls tell me in brief..

Comment: how i can put if condition please tell me?

Comment: It is not an error, it is a warning generated by your IDE, because it was able to infer that there are codepaths where it might be null.

Comment: It will showing another warning as Casting 'findViewById(R.id.textView) to 'TextView' is redundant ..Can anyone help me to resolve this warning ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:
Use a null check first and then invoke a toString();

```
Object obj = dataSnapshot.child("Temperature").getValue();
if(obj!=null)
status = obj.toString();
//handle else condition too
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the `hasChild()` method as a check:

```
@Override
public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {            
  if (dataSnapshot.hasChild("Temperature")) {
    status = dataSnapshot.child("Temperature").getValue().toString();
    Temperature.setText(status);  
  }
}
```